# Xcode Debugger Hover over variable, what does '\ <some stuff> ' mean?

Tags: xcode, debugging

In Xcode (v3.1) debugger if I hover over a struct variable such as `sockaddr_in` I see:

[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/756/picture3ac.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/756/picture3ac.png)

Notice the difference between `sin_port` and `sin_family`/`sin_len`.  What is the meaning of `'\002'` in the case of `sin_family`.  Why is it not displayed as just "2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\002'` means `02` interpreted as an [octal (base 8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number, similar to how `'\x02'` would be the same for a hex (base 16) number. As to why X-Code still uses octal, I'm stumped...

The reason it's only displaying octal representations for those variables is because they are declared as `char`'s. This still doesn't explain the 'why octal' question, but it does answer the 'why' one.

Comment: so sin_len is represented that way because it's of type _uint8_t?

Comment: Presumably. `__uint8_t` boils down to `unsigned byte` on most systems I think you'll find. It is due to it's type though, yes.